# Having A problem with file directory

Tags: tokens, etherscan, brownie

I want to verify the contract using the API etherscan token

**FundMe.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import"node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"; 
import"node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract FundMe {
    

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    
    // if you're following along with the freecodecamp video
    // Please see https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/fund_me
    // to get the starting solidity contract code, it'll be slightly different than this!
  constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        require(
            getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceFeed.version();
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        // minimumUSD
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        uint256 price = getPrice();
        uint256 precision = 1 * 10**18;
        // return (minimumUSD * precision) / price;
        // We fixed a rounding error found in the video by adding one!
        return ((minimumUSD * precision) / price) + 1;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

   
    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

        for (
            uint256 funderIndex = 0;
            funderIndex < funders.length;
            funderIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}
```

***deploy.py***

```
from brownie import FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account





def deploy_fund_me():
  account= get_account()
  # firstly we deploy our contract and then we need to verfiy and publish our smartcontract in etherscan 
  fund_me= FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
  print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")
    


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

**Error that I have**
[image]

**The File path of the AggregatorV3Interface.sol**

[image]

How to sort this bug ?
as the error path is different the the AggregatorV3Interface.sol one

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it as:

```
import"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

[image]

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: Check updated post  - another approach: using SafeMath.sol, you can use Solidity's built-in overflow checking functions. For example, instead of (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;, you can use ethPrice.mul(ethAmount).div(1e18); where mul is equivalent to * and div is equivalent to /. This saves gas by eliminating the need for an external library.